# Dispatch an action from custom functions

Tags: redux, react-redux, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We have an add-in built with ReactJS, redux, and redux-saga. Now, we are adding custom functions to the add-in.

In our manifest, we have the following setting, where `Functions.Taskpane.Url` points to a webpage `ourdomain.com/#/functions`.

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
    <Script>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
    </Script>
    <Page>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Taskpane.Url"/>
    </Page>
    <Metadata>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
    </Metadata>
    <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

The page `ourdomain.com/#/functions` is built with ReactJS and Redux. It's like

```
declare var OfficeRuntime;

interface FunctionsStartProps {
  settings: any;
  key: string
}

const FunctionsStart: React.FunctionComponent<FunctionsStartProps> = ({
  settings, key
}) => {
  console.log("FunctionsStart");

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}

export default withTranslation()(connect((state: ReduxState) => ({
  settings: selectors.settings.getSettings(state),
  key: selectors.settings.getKey(state)        
}))(FunctionsStart));
```

We write all our custom functions in `functions.js`. In one function, we would like to write a logic such that if this function is executed, we dispatch an action to modify the value of `key` in the Redux state.

If it was inside a webpage, dispatching an action would be for instance `this.props.dispatch({ type: 'settings/setKey', payload: "newValue" })`. But we don't know how to trigger this from `functions.js`.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: How exactly does the action need to be dispatched? What is supposed to "trigger" it? Where and when are you wanting to call `this.props.dispatch({ type: 'settings/setKey', payload: "newValue" })`?

Comment: @DrewReese the action to dispatch is indeed `settings/setKey` with `newValue` (which is constant). I just want to trigger it inside a function, any place will be OK.

Comment: So like when the `FunctionsStart` component mounts? or in a UI event callback handler like a button's `onClick`? Please be as specific as possible with regards to any issue you have and what you are wanting to do.

Comment: This is related to custom functions in Excel by JavaScript API. From my understanding, `FunctionsStart` mounts when the user runs custom functions for the first time in a workbook.